# How to set android background color correctly?

Tags: android

i have a question about how to set the alpha only to the color.
Cause background color will take it influence to the color value, like

#### if the background is black,the text background color actually gray unlike the one i want: light white

```
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_adjust_ui"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/text_box"
            android:background="@color/edit_box_color" //#80FFFFFF
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="false"
            />
```

Comment: And now my solution is put one more same view under it for which i need to use relative layout

Comment: What color do you actually want ? you want to use alpha ? or you want to use transparent color ? 
for transparent color you can use 
#00FFFFFF

Comment: and then you can switch values of 00 from the color between 00 to FF.. 
it changes the transparency of the color.

Comment: #00FFFFFF is full transparent.. #FFFFFFFF is no transparent .. 
any value in between #aaFFFFFF is partial transparent.

Comment: i need to set the textview background color to #80FFFFFF,but it's not white when the page's background color is black

Comment: the layout background color affect it

Comment: 80 in start of your color for textview depicts tranparency.. if you have to set it white you have to remove 80... otherwise it will take the color of the background.. whatever it is.

Comment: yeah, but i have to use that color... and how to set the opacity only to the color

Comment: in that case you have to set your background white.

Comment: if a clor code is 8 character long it means first two characters are for opacity..

Comment: Why do you have to use that color? If you set a color that's not 100% opaque, by definition, it's going to blend with what's behind it. Are you sure you don't just want a slightly less-white color; e.g., `#fdfdfd`?

Comment: yeah, that's the color they gave me... but i think maybe i'll just use photoshop something to transform the color into other with same look..

Comment: Do i need close the issue or just leave it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use transparency to TextView background color it will merge with your layout's background color,

You are using  #80FFFFFF for textview background. In this color **80** is transparency no need to set this.

There are two solutions for this.

- Use #FFFFFFFF color textview background,
- Make a [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) [drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource) for textview background,

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: actually this isn't a solution... i need the background color that, yep i knew the 80 mean 80% opacity or 0.8 alpha. And my finnal solution is using photoshop to transform the color with opacity into some value different but has same looking ! And  thank you for your precious time!

Comment: I want to say that don't use opacity use a solid color with no opacity which will help you out.